# How to provide web link of reply email in hero card

Tags: c#, botframework, microsoft-graph-api

I am using Microsoft Graph API v1.0 to list all user emails in hero card with a subject, from and mail body. I added a new button named "Reply" with card action.

```
CardAction(ActionTypes.OpenUrl, "Reply", value: "<<Reply URL>>")
```

**Requirement:**

When I click "Reply", a new tab should open with a specific email account (Gmail, Outlook.com, Office 365 etc.) to send the reply from.

*Note:*

1. User is already authenticated with specific account in browser.
2. Reply To participants is optional when I click that button
3. I am implementing this in Bot Framework V3

Example: I logged into my web outlook account in the browser, when I click "Reply" along with previous messages email thread, it will show us to write mail body, add participants in reply to (in case if we need to add more).

So my requirement of "Reply" button in hero card should work like as example I mentioned.

Is this even possible to provide a WEB LINK for that reply button in hero card of each email? If Yes could let me know for which type of email account supports?

Comment: How do you know which email service account to open?

Comment: We have authentication in bot, based on user email address, we can get to know which account type. Else consider office 365 or outlook account for now.

Comment: Why not use the tools already available? When a user clicks reply open an adaptive card for user input (reply message body, send to's / cc's, etc.). Then use the Microsoft Graph API to send the email based on the values present.

Comment: @steven, approach you said already I know but am thinking in some new approach of replying email. Also there is slight difference between send email and reply email.

Comment: I agree, there is a difference. I was only referring to sending *an* email whether new or a reply. Of note, MS Graph does support creating replies (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-createreply?view=graph-rest-1.0). I don't know if you'll achieve what you want. Seems it would be partially up to the service to provide the right APIs to get you to a screen that is set, on arrival, to send a reply email. As for a web link for each email, how about matching on an array of web links based on the user's auth/email address and send the matched value to the card's reply button?

Comment: Totally agree but what you mean by " Array of web links based on user's Auth".. Can you explain with some example how it can be achieved if possible. Where we can get web links. Which api have to refer?

Comment: @PavanKumarGVVS, You will have to research each service you are interested in to see if that is even something they offer. It isn't something I (or most people) would know.